# How to update ADFS 2.0 Proxy Server Certificate?

Tags: adfs

I have proxy server that sits in the DMZ. The default site is running the adfs and has a certificate that is about to expire in 2 weeks. I am not sure what are steps involved in applying a new ssl certificate. I know at the least I will install the new certificate(s) in the local store. Go to IIS and change the certificate using the binding settings. Is there any othern place I have update the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to replace the cert for the AD FS servers themselves too. And yes you can replace the set is inetmgr.exe console as you mention.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2554.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-replace-the-ssl-service-communications-token-signing-and-token-decrypting-certificates.aspx